# How to create a dimensional model with different metrics depending of the hierarchical level

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I need to create a dimensional environment for sales analysis for a retail company.

The hierarchy that will be present in my `Sales` fact is:

```
1 - Country
1.1 - Region
1.1.1 - State
1.1.1.1 - City
1.1.1.1.1 - Neighbourhood
1.1.1.1.1.1 - Store
1.1.1.1.1.1.1 - Section
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 - Catgory
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 - Subcatgory
1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 - Product
```

Metrics such as `Number of Sales`, `Revenue` and `Medium Ticket` (`Revenue / Number of Sales`) makes sense up to the `Subcategory` level, because if I reach the `Product` level the agreggation composition will need to change (I guess).

Also, metrics such as `Productivity`, which is `Revenue / Number of Store Staff`, won't make sense to existe in this fact table, because it only works up to the `Store` level (also, I guess).

I'd like to know the best solution resolve this question because all of it are about `Sales`, but some makes sense until a specifict level of my hierarchy and others don't.

Waiting for the reply and Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of database or data warehousing software are you using?

Comment: @Salmonerd Oracle 10g with Pentaho Data Integration

Comment: If I wanted to do some sort of reporting or analysis I would just join the data to a table which has all the necessary attribute data for whatever is in your sales records. For example if you has a sales document it would most likely have a store number in it. Then you could join to an attribute table for stores which would store things like country, region, state, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your hierarchy into 2 dimensions, Stores and Products

The Stores dimension is all about the Location of the sale, and you can put the number of employees in this dimension

```
Store_Key  STORE    Neighbourhood    City  Country  Num_Staff
1          Store1   4th Street       LA       US    10
2          Store2   Main Street      NY       US    2
```

The products dimension looks like

```
Product_Key  Prod_Name       SubCat   Category     Unit_Cost
1            Cheese Sticks   Diary    Food         $2.00
2            Timer           Software Computing    $25.00
```

The your fact table has a record for each Sale, and is keyed to the above dimensions

```
Store_Key  Product_Key  Date      Quantity  Tot_Amount
1          1            31/7/2014   5         $10.00   (store1 sells 5 cheese)
1          2            31/7/2014   1         $25.00   (store1 sells 1 timer)
2          1            31/7/2014   3          $6.00   (store2 sells 3 cheese)
2          2            31/7/2014   1         $25.00   (store2 sells 1 timer)
```

Now that your data is in place you can use your reporting tool to get the measures you need. Example SQL is something like below

```
SELECT store.STORE, 
       SUM(fact.tot_amount) as revenue, 
       COUNT(*) as num_sales
       SUM(fact.tot_amount) / store.NumStaff as Productivity
FROM tbl_Store store, tb_Fact fact
WHERE fact.Store_key = store.Store_key
GROUP BY store.STORE
```

should return the following result

```
STORE    revenue    num_sales    Productivity
Store1   $35.00     2            3.5
Store2   $31.00     2            15.5
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I understood your pov. In this case I think there will be more divisions, for example, `Session`, `Category` and `Subcategory` are `Product` attributes. Also, a `Store` can have many departments and each department will have its own `Productivity` analysis.